# sending different array types to different textfiles using one template c++

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, text-files

Trying to get 3 different arrays of varying types to print to separate text files using one template.

Here's what i have:

```
template <class T>
void givetxt(T *a, const int n)
{
    ifstream infile("C:\\.txt", ios::in | ios::app);
    for (int i = 0; i<n; i++)
    {
        infile >> a[i];
    }
    infile.close();
}

template <class T>
void savetxt(const T *a, const int n)
{
    ofstream outfile("C:\\.txt", ios::out | ios::app);
    for (int i = 0; i<n; i++)
        outfile << a[i] << endl;
    outfile.close();
}

int main()
{
    const int n1 = 5, n2 = 7, n3 = 6;
    int a[n1];
    float b[n2];
    char c[n3];

givetxt(a, n1);
savetxt(a, n1);

givetxt(b, n2);
savetxt(b, n2);

givetxt(c, n3);
savetxt(c, n3);
```

right now it sends all of the array data to the .txt. Ideally i'll be able to get it to print to  `.inttxt`, `.floattxt` and  `.chartxt`. i'm not sure how to adjust the infile/outfile to allow for separate text files for the other arrays. i tried pointers but the template wouldn't allow me to relate `T a*` nor `const int n` to the variables i have in `main`. a push in the right direction would be most appreciated.

Comment: How about to write 3 overload functions `savetxt(int*, int)`, `savetxt(float*, int)` and `savetxt(char*, int)` and make them call your template function with 3rd parameter - file name `void savetxt(T *a, const int n, const char* sFileName)`?

Comment: Awesome thank you for your help, this is what ended up working for me. 
       `void savetxt(T *a, const int n, const char* sFileName)
{
 ofstream outfile(sFileName, ios::out | ios::app);
 for (int i = 0; i<n; i++)
  outfile << a[i] << endl;
 outfile.close();
}                                                                                                                  
        savetxt(b, n2, "C:\\Text files\\float.txt");
 savetxt(a, n1, "C:\\Text files\\int.txt");`

Comment: alright well code doesn't come out so great in the comments but it works perfectly, thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this situation overloaded functions (as stated be Artemy Vysotsky in comments) would be best.

For example:

```
template<typename T>
void savetxt(T *a, const int n, const char* sFilename)
{
    ofstream outfile(sFilename, ios::out|ios::app);
    // remaining code to save the file
    ...
    ...
    ...
 }
 void savetxt(int *a, const int n)
 {
    savetxt(a, n, "c:\\inttxt.txt");
 }
 void savetxt(float *a, const int n)
 {
    savetxt(a, n, "c:\\floattxt.txt");
 }
 void savetxt(char *a, const int n)
 {
    savetxt(a, n, "c:\\inttxt.txt");
 }
```